# Allow RDP for user from commandline

Tags: rdp

Is it possible to add a user to the allowed rdp accounts from the commandline?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [`NET`](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html) command:

```
NET LOCALGROUP "Remote Desktop Users" domain\jscott /ADD
```

This would add the domain user *domian\jscott* to the local group *Remote Desktop Users*.  If you'd like to add a non-domain user, simply leave off the domain prefix:

```
NET LOCALGROUP "Remote Desktop Users" keyoke /ADD
```

This would add the local user *keyoke* to the local group *Remote Desktop Users*.

Comment: great if machine is not part of domain would I just use COMPUTER-NAME?

Comment: See edits for adding local user.

Comment: ah crap... dont have sufficient permissions and cant remember my admin password

Comment: @keyoke Have a [quick search of related questions](http://serverfault.com/search?q=reset+admin+password+windows&submit=search), it's not much work to reset the local administrator's password on Windows.

Comment: You may need to set  Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server:fDenyTSConnections to 0 in addition if RDP isn't enabled on the machine