# Adding users from DC to remote desktop users

Tags: domain-controller, rdp, users, user-accounts, rdc

How to add a user from DC to allowed remote desktop users for certain PC?

It lets me choose only users on local machine, although I am connected with a user defined in DC server. A domain user. Even if I try pressing advanced, same thing. Adding domain user to Administrators group is not an option. My goal is choosing from domain users, not local machine ones. Moreover, I am connected with the same user I want to add.

[A screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwu4l.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow RDP for user from commandline](https://serverfault.com/questions/367166/allow-rdp-for-user-from-commandline)

Comment: Problem solved. Needed to switch the local machine to dynamic ip.